# Shopify webp support and image optimization

Tags: shopify, webp, image-optimization

Since Shopify loads images in webp format, I would like to know if I still need to pass my images through optimzation tools like optimazilla. I mean, is it still worth lowering the quality to some degree with those tools or what shopify image optimizer does is enough and I don't need to do that?
Or if I use optimazilla and later shopify converts it to webp, will the image become over-optimized by loosing too much of its quality?

Comment: yeah, Shopify servers the images into the latest web standard webp, but you also need to make sure images are well-sized & optimized means proper dimensions and aspect ratio. Webp format did not make much effect on upload image quality after auto conversion.

Comment: @onkar Thanks for your answer, Onkar. What I meant was, after setting proper dimensions and aspect ratio, will it make a significant difference if I also optimize image with optimazilla or is it a bad practice because using an image optimized by optimazilla and then converted to webp by shopify will decrease the image quality too much?

Comment: no, it doesn't make much quality affect once Sgoppify converts them to Webp format.